# Setting Table Headers and populating Data; Rails and SLIM

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, slim-lang

I am very, very new to rails and slim.

I am trying to create a summary table using

```
h2 Trading History
table.table-striped.table-bordered#analysis
 thead

 tbody
 - @stock_summary[:stocks].each do |key2, value|
   - value.each do |key2, value2|
     tr
      th = key2
      td = value2
```

Unfortunately, the output is forcing the Data into two columns like so:

```
name                          Lennar Corporatio
revenue                       -7320.0
tax_liability                     -0.55
capital_at_risk                0.0
returns                       -1.28
average_holding_period         2.0
capital_invested_percentage        0.0
name                           General Electric
revenue                        2688.89
tax_liability                  0.17
capital_at_risk                0.0
returns                        2.05
average_holding_period         2.7777777777777777
capital_invested_percentage        0.0
```

I would like the Summary Table to use the info (name, revenue, tax_liability, capital_at_risk, returns, average_holding_period, capital_invested_percentage) as the 7 Column headers.

Then I would like to populate the table with the info listed to the right.

As per Jason's comment:
@stock_summary[:stocks].inspect yields:

```
{"LEN"=>{:name=>"Lennar Corporatio", :revenue=>-7320.0, :tax_liability=>-0.55,
:capital_at_risk=>0.0, :returns=>-1.28, :average_holding_period=>2.0, 
:capital_invested_percentage=>0.0}, "GE"=>{:name=>"General Electric", :revenue=>2688.89,
:tax_liability=>0.17, :capital_at_risk=>0.0, :returns=>2.05, 
:average_holding_period=>2.7777777777777777, :capital_invested_percentage=>0.0},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Frank

Comment: Can you post what `@stock_summary[:stocks]` is? Adding in `= @stock_summary[:stocks].inspect` in the html/slim page should show the results on the browser.

Comment: I added what @stock_summary[:stocks] is into the original question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does this work?

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Revenue
      th etc.
  tbody
    - @stock_summary[:stocks].each do |stock, stock_details|
      tr 
        - stock_details.each do |attribute, value|
          td = value
```